# RDD regression discontinuity

Tags: econometrics, regression, difference-in-difference

I have a tiny dataset for several countries: Year (2010-2022) , GDP per capita, Subsidy amount - in the second column (fossilf), and a few other variables. The subsidy amount is 0 for several years.  I would like to see if this subsidy affects gdp growth.The image shows sample data for one country.

My running variable is subsidy amount (fossilf) and I want to estimate the causal effects of subsidy amount on GDP per capita.

As you see, this is a small dataset and I have data for  8 countries. Given this is a really small dataset, it a ridiculous idea to run a regression discontinuity analysis for this?[image]

Comment: Hi Jey, welcome to the econ stackexchange. 
Maybe you can clarify your question more and define what RDD you would run. E.g., what is your running variable, what is the estimation equation.
Also, are you looking for causal identification or "just" robust correlational evidence?

Comment: @MartinGeorgHaas thanks! I will.